# Copy text to clipboard not working in bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, clipboard

It works fine when outside the modal dialog, but when trying copy text to clipboard in bootstrap modal dialog then it does not work.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary-outline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dia">Open</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info-outline btn-sm copy" data-clipboard-text="not in modal"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i></button>

<div id="test" class="modal fade" id="dia" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Test</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info-outline btn-sm copy" data-clipboard-text="in modal">
                        <i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script> 
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy',{
            container: document.getElementById('test'),
        });
</script>
```

This is the sample code for the clipboard function in modal and not in modal. Is there any solution to fix the issue when trying to copy text to clipboard  in modal dialog?

Comment: This may help you - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbxWbQ

Comment: @PhaniKumarM Thanks, but i don't want to copy from an input text field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working "Copy to Clipboard" function doesn't work when called in bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122221/working-copy-to-clipboard-function-doesnt-work-when-called-in-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 5):

refer to [this issue](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/388)

or：

Bootstrap 3

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

Bootstrap 4

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {};
```